# SQL SELECT query where the IDs were already found

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables:
Table A has 3 columns (for example) with opportunity sales header data:

```
OPP_ID, CLOSE_DTTM, STAGE
```

Table B has 3 columns with the individual line items for the Opportunities:

```
OPP_LINE_ID, OPP_ID, AMOUNT_USD
```

I have a select statement that correctly parses through Table A and returns a list of Opportunities. What I would like to do is, **without** joining the data, to have a SELECT statement that will get data from Table B **but only for the OPP_IDs that were found in my first query.**

The result should be 2 views/resultset (one for each select query) and not just 1 combined view where Table B is joined to Table A.

The reason why I want to keep them separate is because I will have to perform a few manipulations to the result from table B and i don't want the result from table A affected.

Comment: could you please add sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. This can be done without using the JOIN keyword, but cannot be done without joining (==relating) the data. Manipulating table B in a database does not necessarily manipulate table A; the only scenario where it does is if there is a foreign key relation that cascades updates made to primary keys in B, into the child key columns in A

Comment: correct the question doesnt make any sense at all

Comment: What is your RDBMS? You could use temp table to get your intermediated result set, then use `JOIN/ IN`..., or duplicate your first query to use in your 2 views...

Comment: Seems you got a simple parent-child relation, i.e. a Foreign Key. If your implementation is correct you can't have details for non-existing opportunities :-)

Answer (score 1):

Subquery is all what you need

```
  SELECT  OPP_ID, CLOSE_DTTM, STAGE
   From  table a
   where a.opp_id IN (Select opp_id from table b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using this in some client side data access library that represents B's data in some 2 dimensional collection and you want to manipulate it without affecting/ having A's data present in that collection:

Identify the records in A:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE somecolumn = 'somevalue'
```

Identify the records in B that relate to A, but **don't return A's data**:

```
SELECT b.* FROM a JOIN b ON a.opp_id = b.opp_id WHERE a.somecolumn = 'somevalue'
```

Just because JOIN is used doesn't mean your end-consuming program has to know about A's data. You could also use IN, like the other answer does, but internally the database will rewrite them to be the same thing anyway

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use `exists` for this type of query:

```
select b.*
from b
where exists (select 1 from a where a.opp_id = b.opp_id);
```

If you want two results sets, you need to run two queries.  It is unclear what the second query is, perhaps the first query on `A`.